# How to create a Xml document with same class, different structures with C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have to create a XML structure but dont know how to do this. I have in one xml document two different structures with the same class. The first structure shows a structure that element  is a List of . Also element  is a list from itself.

The second structure shows that element Member also a List is from . These two structures must generated in one xml document. If I create a another class that is a List and give the Xmlroot with the name "Member", the Xml-Generator give an exception that soms classes have the same name. Can anyone help me to solve this? How to get the structure of Subelements also in these classes?

[First structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4brK.png)

[Second structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSdac.png)

The code of the classes are:

```
public class Section : List<Member>

    public Section() {}
       
    public Section(string aName)
    {
      Name = aName;
    }

    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }



 public class Member : List<Member>
  {
    public Member()
    {
    }

    public Member(string aName, string aDatatype, string aRemanence)
    {
      Name = aName;
      Datatype = aDatatype;
      Remanence = aRemanence;
      Sections = new List<Section>();
    }

    public Member(string aName, string aDatatype, string aAccessibility, string aRemanence)
    {
      Name = aName;
      Datatype = aDatatype;
      Accessibility = aAccessibility;
      Remanence = aRemanence;
    }

    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public string Datatype { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public string Accessibility { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public string Remanence { get; set; }

    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("BooleanAttribute")]
    public bool[] AttributeList{ get; set; }
    public string StartValue { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("MultiLanguageText")]
    public string[] Comment { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can't have both structures.  One is correct and the other is not.  Net library when you define an xml array will automatically create two tags like "Sections" and "Section".  To get one tag you have to add [XmlElement("Section")].  [XmlArrayItem("")] is used to change the tab name of the child tag "Section".  [XmlArray()] is used to change the tag name of the parent tag "Sections".  Do not use XmlArray and XmlArrayItem if you only want one tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want support for all your presented cases and the code model doesn't need to enforce any strict constraints, you can probably design a list of sub-elements with name dependent types (see `Member.SubMember`):

```
public class Section
{
    public Section()
    {
    }

    public Section(string aName)
    {
        Name = aName;
    }

    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Member")]
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
    }

    public Member(string aName, string aDatatype)
    {
        Name = aName;
        Datatype = aDatatype;
    }

    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Datatype { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement("Sections", typeof(List<Section>))]
    [XmlElement("Member", typeof(Member))]
    [XmlElement("Subelement", typeof(SubElement))]
    public List<object> SubMember { get; set; }
}

public class SubElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Path { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string StartValue { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to define a very flexible structure of types below `Member` but on the other side, the C# model doesn't enforce any type constraint here - choose your poison.

This example creates a structure roughly resembling your desired XML (I didn't include all the attributes, since they are not required to discuss the solution):

```
var sections = new List<Section>
{
    new Section("Static")
    {
        Members = new List<Member>
        {
            new Member("Section0", "Struct")
            {
                SubMember = new List<object>()
                {
                    new Member("ACR 5603", "\"UDT ACR Settings\""),
                    new Member("ACR 5604", "\"UDT ACR Settings\"")
                }
            }
        }
    },
    new Section("None")
    {
        Members = new List<Member>
        {
            new Member("CanalFull", "\"UDT_DEV_DIG_INPUT_Settings\"")
            {
                SubMember = new List<object>
                {
                    new List<Section>
                    {
                        new Section("None")
                        {
                            Members = new List<Member>
                            {
                                new Member("SettOnDelay", "Time")
                                {
                                    SubMember = new List<object>
                                    {
                                        new SubElement
                                        {
                                            Path = 1, StartValue = "T#OMS"
                                        },
                                        new SubElement
                                        {
                                            Path = 2, StartValue = "T#OMS"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// Serialize & Deserialize

const string testPath1 = @"C:\[SomeTestPath]\SectionSerialize.xml";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Section>), new XmlRootAttribute("Sections"));

var xmlFile = new FileInfo(testPath1);
using (var fileStream = xmlFile.Open(FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fileStream, sections);
}

using (var fileStream = xmlFile.Open(FileMode.Open))
{
    sections = (List<Section>)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Resulting XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Sections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Section Name="Static">
    <Member Name="Section0" Datatype="Struct">
      <Member Name="ACR 5603" Datatype="&quot;UDT ACR Settings&quot;" />
      <Member Name="ACR 5604" Datatype="&quot;UDT ACR Settings&quot;" />
    </Member>
  </Section>
  <Section Name="None">
    <Member Name="CanalFull" Datatype="&quot;UDT_DEV_DIG_INPUT_Settings&quot;">
      <Sections>
        <Section Name="None">
          <Member Name="SettOnDelay" Datatype="Time">
            <Subelement Path="1">
              <StartValue>T#OMS</StartValue>
            </Subelement>
            <Subelement Path="2">
              <StartValue>T#OMS</StartValue>
            </Subelement>
          </Member>
        </Section>
      </Sections>
    </Member>
  </Section>
</Sections>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The only XML element what I may not have is <Members> in your case. In your example could I make than public class Section : List<Member> to solve everything?

Comment: I'm using `XmlSerializer` in this example and it doesn't play nice when deriving from `List<Member>` with additional properties (`[XmlAttribute]`), so I replaced the inheritance by a property. Also, I think the property approach allows more fine grained control over the serialization details. I typically wouldn't derive from `List<Anything>`.